# AWS CodeBuild Docker images as Base Image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Are [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html) images availabe to be used as base image in my own Dockerfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not published anywhere as of yet. There is a ticket that claims they will publish Amazon Linux 2 based images once they are ready:

https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/issues/199

If you want to use them as a base image you need to check out the project yourself and build them locally:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images.git
$ cd aws-codebuild-docker-images
$ cd ubuntu/standard/2.0
$ docker build -t aws/codebuild/standard:2.0 .
```

Once you have it built locally, you can reference it from your local Dockerfile:

```
FROM aws/codebuild/standard:2.0
```

and it will use your local cached image. You can then publish your image to ECR to use for your codebuild projects.

Answer (score 2):

These images can be used for CodeBuild Projects.

For example: You have a node.js application and want to run your tests on CodeBuild. In this case you want to use the node.js codebuild docker image: `ubuntu/nodejs/10.14.1`

You should not use these images as a base-image for your applications. But you can use them as base-image for other codebuild docker images.

Comment: I would like to build a custom image for CodeBuild, but I couldn't find a repo where these are available.

Comment: We have just used some images from docker-hub, for example for android builds. You can also build your own images. You can also build from these base-images, but you have to upload these into your own ECR or Docker-Hub by yourself before. I dont think, that these images are already uploaded on any public docker-repository.